# How to get a reference to a method's caller object from within the method in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a few text fields and text views on my application's view. The keyboard comes up when I click in anyone of them. I have a method that gets called when any one of these objects is tapped in. However, I would like the method to execute its code only if the a certain Text Field(s) or a certain Text View(s) is tapped in. I would therefore like to have something like this in the method body:

```
{
   if(currentField != mySpecialField)
      {return;}

     //Rest of the method code...
}
```

Now, my question is, how do I get a reference to the currently tapped in field so that I can perform the if-check.

#### Update:

In my situation, I am using the code I got from Apple's website that makes use of these methods:

```
// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    if (keyboardShown)
        return;

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    // Get the size of the keyboard.
    NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

    // Resize the scroll view (which is the root view of the window)
    CGRect viewFrame = [scroller frame];
    viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
    scroller.frame = viewFrame;

    // Scroll the active text field into view.
    CGRect textFieldRect = [activeField frame];
    [scroller scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];

    keyboardShown = YES;
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWasHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    // Get the size of the keyboard.
    NSValue* aValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];
    CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;

    // Reset the height of the scroll view to its original value
    CGRect viewFrame = [scroller frame];
    viewFrame.size.height += keyboardSize.height;
    scroller.frame = viewFrame;

    keyboardShown = NO;
}
```

Can I modify these methods in such a way that I can get a reference to the caller UITextField and / or the caller UITextView?

#### Update:

Here's the method that's used for registration:

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.


- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve what I'm trying to achieve? Maybe if I modify the code above to pass 'object:self' instead of 'object:nil'?

Answer (score 3):

Controls that are subclasses of `UIControl` (for example `UIButton` or `UITextField`) automatically sends a reference to themselves along to their target.

When creating your text fields, just specify a selector that takes one argument. In this example, "myTextField" is an instance variable:

```
myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 40)];
[myTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then the method we specified, `textFieldTapped:`, to handle the event:

```
- (void)textFieldTapped:(UITextField *)sender {
    // Ignore any events that doesn't come from myTextField
    if (sender != myTextField) return;

    // TODO: Do stuff
}
```

In the case of `UITextField` you can also check out the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol (the "delegate" value of your text field). It sends out various events that can be used to register the same kind of things, for example:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```